# com.paypal.base.exception.HttpErrorException: retry fails.. check log for more information

Tags: paypal

> enviroment/mode sandbox
>   com.paypal.base.exception.HttpErrorException: retry fails.. check log for more information

getting this error when requesting

```
new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID,clientSecret,sdkConfig).getAccessToken();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.